# Trying to compile libmemcached in Solaris 10 SPARC

Tags: perl, solaris, sparc, libmemcached

I have a SPARC enterprise server with Solaris 10 SPARC OS installed.  I have unpacked the tarball file 'libmemcached-0.10.tar.gz' into a directory and I am trying to compile it. I get the following error on terminal

```
pod2man: command not found
```

What do I do next?

Comment: Try install [`Pod::Man`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod::Man). It should give you the script [`pod2man`](https://metacpan.org/pod/pod2man)

Comment: How do I do that Hakon?

Comment: There are many ways to install CPAN modules, see e.g. [How to install CPAN modules](https://www.cpan.org/modules/INSTALL.html)

Comment: Do you have `/usr/perl5/bin` in your `$PATH`?

Answer (score 1):

It should be under `/usr/perl5` somewhere. Try:
`find /usr/perl5 -name pod2man`
Or if you have a local version, look under `/usr/local`
Then add the directory to your `$PATH` in `$HOME/.profile`

Comment: I have found it thanks :). but I now have another problem, libmemcahced still wont compile propertly here is the output from the terminal in Solaris 10 SPARC

Comment: [CODE}
gmake[1]: Entering directory `/export/home/Repo/libmemcached-0.18/tests'
/bin/bash ../libtool --preserve-dup-deps --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc  -Wall -O3 -DMEMCACHED_INTERNAL    -o testapp test.o function.o server.o generator.o execute.o ../libmemcached/libmemcached.la [/CODE]

Comment: gcc -Wall -O3 -DMEMCACHED_INTERNAL -o .libs/testapp test.o function.o server.o generator.o execute.o  ../libmemcached/.libs/libmemcached.so  -R/usr/local/lib

Comment: Undefined   [[LARGE SPACE. AS THESE REPRESENT COLUMN HEADERS]]   first referenced

Comment: sendto       [[LARGE SPACE]]                      ../libmemcached/.libs/libmemcached.so

Comment: socket     [[LARGE SPACE]]       ../libmemcached/.libs/libmemcached.so

Comment: setsockopt          [[LARGE SPACE]]         ../libmemcached/.libs/libmemcached.so

Comment: getsockopt           [[LARGE SPACE]]              ../libmemcached/.libs/libmemcached.so

Comment: connect      [[LARGE SPACE]]           ../libmemcached/.libs/libmemcached.so

Comment: getaddrinfo        [[LARGE SPACE]]                 ../libmemcached/.libs/libmemcached.so

Comment: freeaddrinfo               [[LARGE SPACE]]          ../libmemcached/.libs/libmemcached.so

Comment: ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to .libs/testapp
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [testapp] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/export/home/Repo/libmemcached-0.18/tests'
gmake: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Comment: HOW DO I GET AROUND THIS?

Answer (score 1):

For your other errors you need to link in libsocket, `-lsocket`. See the *Programming Interfaces Guide, Chapter 8 Socket Interfaces* at https://docs.oracle.com/
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/817-4415/sockets-85885/index.html

In general, if you have a undefined interface error during linking, you need to add a library containing those missing interfaces.